# Multithreading in PHP

Tags: php, multithreading

I recently read about http://php.net/pcntl and was woundering how good that functions works and if it would be smart to use multithreading in PHP since it isn't a core function of PHP.

I would want to trigger events that don't require feedback through it like fireing a cronjob execution manually.

All of it is supposed to run in a web app written with Zend Framework

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pcntl package works quite fine - it just uses the according [unix functions](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork). The only shortage is that you can't use them if php is invoked from a web server context. i.e. you can use it in shell scripts, but not on web pages - at least not without using a hack like [calling a forking script with exec](http://joseph.randomnetworks.com/archives/2005/10/21/fake-fork-in-php/) or similar.

[edit]
I just found a page explaining [why mod_php cannot fork](http://www.mail-archive.com/php-bugs@lists.php.net/msg95558.html). Basically it's a security issue.
[/edit]

Comment: damn it I wanted to use it in a webapp :(

Answer (score 4):

This is not thread control, this is process control. The library for the threads is [pthreads (POSIX threads)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) and it's not included in PHP, so there are no multi-threading functions in PHP.

As of multiprocessing, you cannot use that in mod_php, as that would be a giant security hole (spawned process would have all the web-server's privileges).

Answer (score 2):

The only possible way to have php code executing in multiple threads is to run php as a module of a threaded web server, which is useless because threads are fully isolated and your code has no control over them. As far as i know, pcntl only manages processes, not threads.

Answer (score 2):

If I needed to do manual crontab executions or the like from PHP, I'd probably use a queue. Have a database table that you append jobs to. Another process, either from a cron or running as a daemon, executes the jobs as they show up.

Another way to do it is to set up a separate script and do an HTTP GET to it. It's not quite threading, but it's one way of shelling to another command in PHP.

For example, if I wanted to run `/usr/bin/somescript.sh` on demand, I'd have a `somescript.php` that did a system call. This would be on a virtual host only accessible from localhost.

I'd do a socket call to the webserver and GET the script. The key is to *not* read on the socket so it doesn't block. If I wanted to check the return value of `somescript.php`, I'd do it later in my main script to prevent blocking.

If `somescript.php` takes a long time to execute (longer than the calling script), you'll have to do some magic to stop apache from killing the script when the socket is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplatform PHP Multithreading engine
http://anton.vedeshin.com/articles/lightweight-and-multiplatform-php-multithreading-engine

Comment: Link is dead. Was that your website?

Answer (score 1):

Examples of multithreading working in PHP (with excerpts from their project pages):

- [Cron Multi-Threaded](https://www.drupal.org/project/cron_mt).

> As of October 25th, 2011, this module has reached "end of life" and is deprecated in favor of projects such as [Elysia Cron](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron). This module wasn't completely useless in that a core patch inspired by Cron MT was committed to D7.

- [Boost](https://www.drupal.org/project/boost).

> ... provides static page caching for Drupal enabling a very significant performance and scalability boost for sites that receive mostly anonymous traffic. For shared hosting this is your best option in terms of improving performance. On dedicated servers, you may want to consider Varnish instead.