# how to run a php function (not external process) in the background?

Tags: php, background

How can I run a PHP function in background, not a process? For instance, I have to do:

```
(php code)
1º) retrieve data from database#1
2º) retrieve data from database#2
3º) If #1 and #2 have finished, do my calculations.
```

Functions #1 and #2 are also PHP code. I don't want to use "exec" or "system", as they are not external processes, they are also PHP code! I imagine there should exist some smart way to run a PHP function or line in the background, just that. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

PHP doesn't do multi-threading*, so what you want to do is not possible inside the same script.

You would need to start a separate PHP process that works through a separate script.

<sub>*) [there is `pcntl_fork`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590684/multithreading-in-php) for CLI and possibly CGI mode but it has pitfalls, documentation and examples on this seem sparse, it is limited to Unix/Linux, and I am assuming you are in a web page context anyway where it doesn't work.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a `cURL multi handler`, which can run different scripts (and get the data from them) in parallel. This, in my opinion, is the best option for running multi-threaded scripts in PHP.

You'd have to change things around though - the function(s) that you'd want to run in the background would have to be moved into their own script, and called individually by the cURL handler.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

Here's some examples of use:

http://codestips.com/php-multithreading-using-curl/

https://web.archive.org/web/20091014034235/http://www.ibuildings.co.uk/blog/archives/811-Multithreading-in-PHP-with-CURL.html

Answer (score 0):

As other posters said, threading is not possible directly.

As far as your specific question, there are ways of doing it.  You could use [`MySQLi::multi_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).  The first query needs to finish before you can use the results from the second query

```
$mysqli->multi_query($sql1 . ';' . $sql2);
$result1 = $mysqli->store_result();
$rows1 = $result1->fetch_all();
$result2 = $mysqli->store_result();
$rows2 = $result2->fetch_all();
```

Both queries are executed side by side.  The results are returned synchronously, but it works.

You could also emulate threads using a [`register_tick_function()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php).  There are [some docs](http://www.phpdig.net/ref/rn62.html) online about [to actually](http://www.youngcoders.com/php-articles/22319-ticks-php-construct-youve-never-used.html) use ticks [for threading](http://phpadvocate.com/blog/?p=102).  But I have to warn you, it's usually a **very bad idea** to try to abuse them in this way, since it's not really true threading it won't behave like it (statements are still executed in order, so a blocking statement will block everything).

Answer (score 0):

Php does support threading
*(requires PECL pthreads >= 0.34)*

you will find an example here http://php.net/manual/en/thread.start.php